# How to assign a variable as Id in Jquery function for autocomplete text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a text area that calling a jQuery function for autocomplete the fields.
But my textArea Ids are dynamically creating and i have to pass those ids, when ever clicking the text area.

But the variable in the jQuery function is not working here is my code

```
   function SearchText(id) {
           var   TxtboxId ="";
           TxtboxId = "#IdPrefix_" + id;

      $(TxtboxId).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "demo.aspx/GetAutoCompletfunc",
          data:'{"key":"' + request.term +'"}',              
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
                   response(data.d);
                 },
             error: function(result) {
             alert("Error");
             }
            });
            }
          });
      }
```

Calling this function by text area onclick event. This code is added in a loop for dynamicallly create the text areas. here calling the SearchText Function.

```
ListArr[++j] = '<td width="20%" ><textarea id="IdPrefix_' + id  + '" type="textbox" onclick = "javascript:SearchText( ' + id + ' );"  maxlength="300"
```

But it is not working in  `$(TxtboxId).autocomplete`

Anyone know any solution? please answer.

Comment: Check your browser console to see if there is any error ?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log()`ging `TxtboxId` to see if it has the expected value?

Comment: Values are coming properly , But it is not considering as ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select the element type and get the id from the event

see demo here [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jz73pLx/1/)

```js
var sourceStub = [
    {label: "bat", value: "batman"},
    {label: "cat", value: "catwomen"},
    {label: "rat", value: "mighty mouse"},
    {label: "dog", value: "lassie"}
];

$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    $("#" + e.target.id).autocomplete({
        source: sourceStub
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td width="20%" >
        <textarea id="IdPrefix_1" type="textbox"></textarea>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td width="20%" >
        <textarea id="IdPrefix_2" type="textbox"></textarea>
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

or if you have textareas you dont want to participate in the autocomplete fun you can create a class

```
.autoCompleteMe {}
```

and add that class to each element you want to run autocomplete on

```
<textarea class="autoCompleteMe" id="IdPrefix_1" type="textbox"></textarea>
```

and select that class instead

```
$(".autoCompleteMe").keyup(...);
```

Comment: Its also Working fine. But my code is correct only one thing i have changed. its given below

Answer (score 1):

The TxtboxId only have to split, that is it cannot implicitly add '#'
with it

```
       TxtboxId = "IdPrefix_" + id;
       $("#" + TxtboxId).autocomplete({
          -------------});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better we could add a attribute to the text box

like following way . put a class attribute as "ckeditor" and do following

```
 var TxtboxId = $(this).find('.ckeditor').attr("id");
```

Comment: But id is  , ` id="IdPrefix_' + id "` again i have to add that variable in .attr(variable) @ASADUL